# SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet) results if not select query

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I need to know the results of SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet) in case the executed query is not select statement.

Example: when the user inputs an insert statement instead of select statement, the data adapter executes it even if it is not select statement, how to know the results of the executed statement?

Comment: Have you considered running your code?

Comment: Yes, it returns empty dataset, but the delete statement which is provided to the data adapter is executed.

Comment: The entire point of a method named `Fill` is to fill something. If you're not filling a `DataTable` - in a `DataSet` or not - then DO NOT call `Fill` on a data adapter. If you want to execute a `DELETE` statement then call `ExecuteNonQuery`, like you're supposed to.

Comment: What resultset are you expecting `INSERT INTO Person VALUES('Imad')` to produce?

Comment: Letting users enter arbitrary sql and then executing it is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment elsewhere you wrote:

> But I cannot control the user from writing only select statements. Because it will be used by IT staff. in case of the user needs to insert data into a table and used the same page it will be executed.

This is really quite easy to solve:

```vb
    Dim sql = whatTheUserWrote.Trim()

    Dim sc = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

    If "SELECT WITH".Split().Any(Function(s) sql.StartsWith(s, sc)) Then

      'uses something like: dbDataAdapter.Fill(someDatatable)
      RunSqlUsingDataAdapterFill(sql)

    Else If "INSERT UPDATE DELETE".Split().Any(Function(s) sql.StartsWith(s, sc)) Then

      'uses something like: Dim rowsAffected = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
      RunSqlUsingCommandExecuteNonQuery(sql)
  
    Else 

      Throw New ArgumentException("The SQL provided must start with one of these following words: SELECT WITH INSERT UPDATE DELETE", whatTheUserWrote, NameOf(whatTheUserWrote))

    End
```

BTW, I think it's a monstrously bad idea to create an SQL query client for users, but it's not my job on the line! Hope your table/row level permissions are really well sorted for this one

Comment: But what if the SQL statement starts with whitespace? Or like `/* SELECT * FROM Foo */ DELETE FROM Foo`? It is not easy to parse SQL as mere strings.

Comment: *But what if the SQL statement starts with whitespace?*  `Dim sql = whatTheUserWrote.Trim()` <-- TRIM.

Comment: It might not be easy to parse SQL as strings, but it's real easy to impose a set of rules on the most destructive feature you can offer the users. If they can't follow simple instruction it's a great decider as to whether they should have access to the feature or not ;)

Answer (score 0):

> [Docs: DataAdapter.Fill Method#Fill(DataSet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=netcore-3.1#System_Data_Common_DataAdapter_Fill_System_Data_DataSet_)
>
> The Fill method retrieves rows from the data source using the SELECT statement specified by an associated SelectCommand property.

> [Docs: IDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbdataadapter.selectcommand?view=netcore-3.1)
>
> If the SelectCommand does not return any rows, no tables are added to the DataSet, and no exception is raised.

So your adapter will remain empty.

Comment: But the statement will be executed. How to know the result of executing the provided statement?

Comment: You're asking the wrong questions. If your users can enter arbitrary SQL, why do you execute it through `DataSet.SelectCommand`? It's a particular API that helps you for example fill UI grids from database tables with very few lines of code. If you want to execute SQL that may not select records but update them instead, use a different API.

Comment: The case is that I have a page in my system to allow users to write sql select statements to view as table. But I cannot control the user from writing only select statements. Because it will be used by IT staff. in case of the user needs to insert data into a table and used the same page it will be executed.

Comment: But what "results" are you looking for then? In the case of an INSERT or UPDATE statement, it's not possible to obtain the "n rows affected" this way, because that whole API you're using is not meant to do that. If you want a reasonably functional system, you could parse the SQL that the user enters and detect whether it contains a SELECT statement. If not, execute the SQL through a different API. Also, I wouldn't give users (admins or not) the ability to execute raw SQL through a web application. What if they paste `DELETE FROM Users` and execute that? Do you have a backup?